# Looking for an alien invasion book

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Long time ago, like 45 years ago or more, I read a book where Earth had been invaded by an alien space empire. Problem was, for the aliens, that on average humans were more intelligent than the aliens. Humans spread out throughout the empire and cause all kinds of chaos and confusion.

The book ends with the empire having crushed all rebellion with the help of a now independent Earth and the humans confronted, together with the aliens, are now confronted with a third alien race that is more intelligent than humans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be *Pandora's Planet* by Christopher Anvil.  It's a one-for-one match with your question.

It started as a story "Pandora's Planet" in *Astounding* in 1956 and was expanded into a novel in 1972.  The Centrans -- a well-meaning Galactic empire discovers Earth and plans to bring it into the essentially benign Empire.  Humans don't go along and it turns out that humans are considerably smarter on average than Centrans.  There are amusing scenes -- especially in the early parts of the novel which came form the original story -- of the invaders being overwhelmed by human inventiveness and persistence.  (Later the book tends to get a bit didactic.)

In the last scene, a combined human-Centran polity is faced with a new race whose average member is a genius by human standards.

Comment: It seems *Pandora's Planet* (1972) was further expended to *Pandora's Legions* (2007).